# Default mime type icons from Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I use Alfresco and CMIS.
Is it possible to get mime type icons using CMIS and context, please?
If here: https://www.alfresco.com/abn/adf/docs/core/services/thumbnail.service/#mat-icon
I want only default mime type icons not thumbnails.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this post is 8+ years old, I believe it still applies: [From CMIS how do I get the thumbnail placeholder for Alfresco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652985/from-cmis-how-do-i-get-the-thumbnail-placeholder-for-alfresco)

Basically, CMIS would only return the thumbnail image and not the placeholder (which is what you want).

However, you may goto the mimetype image directly via extension:

Share:

> http://localhost/share/components/images/filetypes/(extension)-file-48.png
>
> Example:
>
> http://localhost/share/components/images/filetypes/jpg-file-48.png

Alfresco:

> http://localhost/alfresco/images/filetypes/(extension).png
>
> Example:
>
> http://localhost/alfresco/images/filetypes/jpg.png